# ionic build error reflect metadata

Tags: node.js, windows, ionic-framework, npm, installation

I've transferred an ionic application from a Mac computer to my Windows computer.
The ionic installation and everything ran fine, however the moment that I try to run 'ionic serve' or 'ionic build' I get an error saying

```
 "Error: Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'
```

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

I have read forums which mention adding the line

```
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
```

and i have done so with no luck.

Please help!

Comment: Run `npm install --save reflect-metadata` from the command line.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Thank you! That seems to have worked, however its now creating an error     "Error: Cannot find module '@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc'. I have run the 'npm install  -g @angular/cli' with no luck.

Comment: Maybe this discussion has a solution for you? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3183